# Name of this kind of architecture

Tags: architecture

I'm using a drag-drop graphical developed tool-kit which is built on top a platform.

After an artifact of this kind(essentially graphical representations of java classes) is made, the platform would generate codes and store them into database. 
When in runtime, the platform would read codes from database, use reflection to instantiate the class, wire beans and do the work.

I'm curious of this architecture and wondering how I can figure out how it works without the codes of the platform.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't an architecture, it's a tool.  Tools like these are often referred to as [RAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development) tools.  They are focused on building small, simple applications very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This way of development can be termed as Model driven development https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_engineering

In Model driven development you model your domain objects, their relationships, their persistence etc. This is done through a tool. Your domain can be anything starting from UI objects/screens to Business objects.

One of the famous tools/framework is Eclipse modeling framework (EMF) which helps you to achieve the same https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Modeling_Framework

Comment: thanks for informing. I newly joined a company in which developers are to use this kind of graphical building tool-kit. As I'm going thru the training I didnt found it particularly fast or handy. first, configurations of interacting artifacts(or building blocks or widgets or the like) could be much convoluted. second, the debugging degenerated to merely checking input and output at the junctions.